# Fibonacci eigen basis - Linear algebra | Matrices | Eigen basis | 3blue1brown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

what is the intuition behind - [image]

I can understand why this formula - [image] exists but not the former one.

[image]

Could anyone please explain the way they explain it in this  [website](https://dandavison.github.io/fibonacci-eigenbasis.html) ?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why don't you compute this for $n=1$ and $n=2$ first? This is independent of Fibonacci.

Comment: As it says there, the reason for converting from $A$ to $V^{-1}AV$ is that $V^{-1}AV$ is a diagonal matrix, so easier than $A$ to exponentiate

Comment: If your question is why $A^n = V(V^{-1}AV)^nV^{-1}$... notice that things simplify considerably.  Also, remember that since matrix multiplication is not commutative the exponent does not simply "distribute" over everything, but rather remember that $(ABC)^n = \underbrace{(ABC)(ABC)\cdots (ABC)}_{n~\text{times}}$.  For your specific case $(V^{-1}AV)^n = (V^{-1}AV)(V^{-1}AV)(V^{-1}AV)\cdots$

Comment: The specific property you are referring to is not limited to dealing only with fibonacci numbers or the fibonacci matrix operation itself, but rather has much broader implications and uses.  It just so happens that the example and motivation behind the example you are working with has to do with fibonacci numbers, but beyond that we can completely ignore the relevance.  Your matrix operation (*which happens to describe a way of generating the fibonacci sequence using matrices*) can be diagonalized (*as can many other matrices*) and so when applied many times successively can be simplified.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, i think the way i made my question has made everyone misunderstand what i need, sorry for that. What i need is, why we have to do the first formula after we derive the latter one & what happens geometrically when we try to do so ?

Comment: The intuition behind the exponential is to obtain the nth fibo number on a matrix $A^n$, thus if $A$ is diagonalizable, represent is as $VAV^{-1}$, then exponentiate the diagonal matrix as it's easier to exponentiate than $A$ itself. That's why.

Comment: Thank you! @kubOx